# Taylor series for $f(z)=\frac{\exp(z^2)}{z^3-1}$ with recursive coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

> Let $f(z)=\frac{\exp(z^2)}{z^3-1}$, $z\in\mathbb{C}$, and show that the Taylor series for $f$ around $0$ has the form
>   $$ f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_k z^k$$
>   where $a_0=-1$, $a_1=0$, $a_2=-1$, and $a_{2k+1}=a_{2k-2}$, $a_{2k+2}=a_{2k-1}-\frac{1}{(k+1)!}$ 
>   for $k\geq1$.

I found the Taylor series for $\exp(z^2)$ around $0$, and found that
$$ f(z)=\frac{1}{z^3-1} \exp(z^2)=\frac{1}{z^3-1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} z^{2k}$$

but now I have no ideas on how to proceed. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $(z^3-1) f(z) = \exp(z^2)$.  If $f(z) = \sum_k a_k z^k$, what are the coefficients of $z^{2k+1}$ and $z^{2k+2}$  in both sides of that equation?

Comment: Thanks. I get $(z^3-1) a_{2k+1}  = \frac{1}{(2k+1)!}z^{2k+1}$, but I'm not sure what it's supposed to lead to, am I on the right track?

Comment: No, that's not quite right.

Comment: The coefficient of a particular power of $z$ will not have a $z$ in it.